# Is there a Driver for mongodb to use Atlas search in .net core application?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I'm using MongoDB Atlas in my .net core application, using c# driver to connect the database, recently came to know about Atlas Search and I'm able to create an index for my collections, Is there a way to use $searchbeta from my application to query my index?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `aggregate` method and `BsonDocument.Parse`:

```
var pipeline = BsonDocument.Parse("{ $searchBeta: { search: { path: 'foo', query : 'bar' } }}");
var result = col.Aggregate<BsonDocument>(pipeline);
```

Comment: when i use this i get compilation error as below:                                                                                                        Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0411 The type arguments for method 'IMongoCollection<BookEntity>.Aggregate<TResult>(PipelineDefinition<BookEntity, TResult>, AggregateOptions, CancellationToken)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: added type argument

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/)

For c# driver see Pipelines section in the [Definitions and Builders](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/reference/driver/definitions/) docs

```
var pipeline = new BsonDocument[] 
{
    BsonDocument.Parse("{ $searchBeta: ... }"),
    BsonDocument.Parse("{ $sort: ... }")
};
var result = _db.GetCollection<Person>("people").Aggregate<Person>(pipeline).ToList();
```